# How to separate the maximum count for each genre of something

Tags: mysql

I want to find for each
genre of movie, find the N actors who have played in most movies
of the genre

I have done this:

```
select genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id,count(genre.genre_name) from genre
inner join movie_has_genre on movie_has_genre.genre_id=genre.genre_id
inner join movie on movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
inner join role on movie.movie_id=role.movie_id
inner join actor on actor.actor_id=role.actor_id
group by genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id;
```

which gives as a result for each genre how many movies of that genre every actor has played and now i want to find for each genre the actor that has played the most moviesof that genre.

```
Tables and their columns:

actor(actor_id,name)
role(actor_id,movie_id)
movie(movie_id,title)
movie_has_genre(movie_id,genre_id)
genre(genre_id,genre_name)
```

Also the result should be something like this:

```
Action 22591 7
Horror 25863 3
Horror 24867 3
Comedy 23476 2
Drama  14536 1
Drama  19634 1
Drama  17563 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, what I'd do is the next (supposing your code is working well):

```
-- Notice this is your code with some aliases, nothing else.
-- Just for making mi job easier.
create view frequency as
select genre.genre_name as genre_ name, 
       actor.actor_id as actor_id,
       count(genre.genre_name) as freq
from genre
inner join movie_has_genre on movie_has_genre.genre_id=genre.genre_id
inner join movie on movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
inner join role on movie.movie_id=role.movie_id
inner join actor on actor.actor_id=role.actor_id
group by genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id;

-- And this is my proposal
-- Take the max frequency per each category
-- and find the guy who possesses it (maybe 2 or more...)
select genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id
from frequency as tbl1 inner join
(
  -- The max frequency in a genre.
  select f.genre_name,
         max(f.freq) as max_freq
  from frequency f
  group by(genre_name)
) as tbl2 on (tbl1.genre_name = tbl2.genre_name)
where tbl1.freq = tbl2.max_freq;
```

And well, there's one problem: It may return more than one actor per category, if there's a tie. But how can I know who is the winner? I let it for you. Maybe it's wrong, I don't think so, but we're both learning! Hope I'd help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `MAX()` function. Some SQL implementations (such as Oracle) allow you to do this: `SELECT MAX(COUNT(whatever))` but MySQL isn't one of them.

One way to do what you want is this:

```
select genre_name, actor_id, max(genrecount)
from (
    select genre.genre_name, actor.actor_id, count(genre.genre_name) as genrecount
    from genre
    inner join movie_has_genre on movie_has_genre.genre_id=genre.genre_id
    inner join movie on movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
    inner join role on movie.movie_id=role.movie_id
    group by genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id
) as topactor
```

This does the outer `SELECT` on the table derived from the inner `SELECT`.

Comment: it doesnt recognise genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id on the outer select

Comment: @stef My mistake, sorry. I forgot to remove the references to the actual tables when I copied it from your original, which you have to do because you're referring to the results of the inner select. (You could say `topactor.genre_name`, etc. as well.) I've edited my answer.